# Logstash: Create new filed and get dynamic key value from json in ruby

Tags: json, ruby, dynamic, logstash

I am new to JSON data and Ruby.

I am looking for ways to get dynamic key value from JSON.

My JSON data is like below:

```
{
  "shyap" : {
    "enabled" : true,
    "roles" : [
      "superuser",
      "reportinguser"
    ],
    "rules" : {
      "any" : [
        {
          "field" : {
            "dn" : "CN=shyap,OU=IT,OU=MY,DC=DomainName,DC=local"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "metadata" : { }
  },
  "john" : {
    "enabled" : true,
    "roles" : [
      "developer"
    ],
    "rules" : {
      "any" : [
        {
          "field" : {
            "dn" : "CN=john,OU=IT,OU=MY,DC=DomainName,DC=local"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "metadata" : { }
  }
}
```

My filter is like below:

```
filter {
  ruby {
    code => "
      require 'json'
      text = event.get('message')
      parsed = JSON.parse(text)
    "
  }
}
```

How do i loop through the JSON data and flatten the result to:

[image: result_table]

Comment: Can you post a sample of the code you have tried?

Comment: @tabur check this link -> https://discuss.elastic.co/t/indent-any-json-file-nested-fields-and-make-it-flat/194447/2 It talks about flattening but you can apply filter on top of flattening to get only the keys you are after.

Comment: if parsed != nil
       parsed.each { |key, value|
         myhash = {'userid' => key,
                  'subvalue' => value
                  }
         puts JSON.generate(myhash)
       }
     end

Comment: i manage to solve this problem. Anyone interested can refer to: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-manipulate-json-data/254198?u=nameisnotimportant